# Jolt Transformation - Replace text on json

Tags: json, jolt

I would like to replace all "test" if exists with "" string

```json
{
  "ids": {
    "id1": "testT123",
    "id2": "test123asd",
    "id3": "1234"
  }
}
```

Desired Output:

```json
{
  "ids" : {
    "id1" : "T123",
    "id2" : "123asd",
    "id3" : "1234"
  }
}
```

I am trying to use ***"operation": "modify-overwrite-beta"*** but not able to figure out how to modify a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consecutively apply **split** and **join** functions along with ***modify-overwrite-beta*** spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=split('test',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]